# How some apk are stored by Android

Tags: android, security, apk

I know that the apk are stored in /data/app with the name of the package (and "-1" at the end).

On not-root phone is not possiple to list (ls) the file contained in /data/app, however since I knon the filename I can copy the apk from /data/app to /mnt/sdcard/whereeveriwant/, even without root permission.

```
public static void copyFile(String inputPath, String inputFile, String outputPath) {
InputStream in = null;
OutputStream out = null;
try {
    //create output directory if it doesn't exist
    File dir = new File (outputPath); 
    if (!dir.exists()) { dir.mkdirs(); }
    in = new FileInputStream(inputPath + inputFile);        
    out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + inputFile);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    in.close();
    in = null;
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    out = null;        
}  catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
    Log.e("copy", fnfe1.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("copy", e.getMessage());
}
}
copyFile(
        "/data/app/", "com.myawesomeapp.android-1.apk",
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + folder + File.separator
);
```

However for some apps (not free app as far as I know) this method is not working. 
Do the apk have a different name? Or it is forward locked?

This is a research question, no practical use is intended.

Comment: Try the `/system/app` directory.

Comment: I tried, but it is not working. Anyway I believe that /system/app contain only system app such Contacts.apk and Calculator.apk

Comment: You could use 'adb shell pm list package -f' to list all the installed apps, including the package name and apk location.

Comment: I did not know this command, it helped me a lot. The pay-app are saved in /mnt/asec/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I got it: free apps are decrypted and the APKs end up in /data/app, while an encrypted container in /data/app-asec is created and mounted under /mnt/asec/package.name for paid apps.